# Image not showing up fullscreen

Tags: java, image, frame, fullscreen

I am working on a project using Eyetribe and I need the images to be fullscreen in order to make it work effectively.
I am currently drawingImage. But for some reason, it only draws those images which I have previously drawn without using it int the main program.
In my test program, I just made a method where I was drawing the image to see if it worked. It worked perfectly. 
I then wrote a main program where I draw images, for some reason, it only shows images which I drew using my test program. Earlier I thought it wasn't getting enough time to render as I was drawing 22 times in a single second. But now I only draw it once and then don't touch the drawing method again. But it still only seems to show the images that I have drawn before. Also, in my main program, I am using the Eyetribe which updates at least 22 times every second. Could that be the reason that its not drawing?

UPDATE: TO fix the above issue I am now using paintComponent. I am just having issues switching between images now. Below the method, showFrame is called initially to draw. And then I am using the switchImageTest to switch images when right arrow is pressed. In the key listener method, I am basically updating the image index and calling switchImageTest. Could anyone point me in the right direction as to why its not working?

The method I am using to draw is below:

image is the image I am trying to paint.

Method which is called initially to build the frame/label etc.

```
public void showFrame(int imageIndex) throws IOException{
    System.out.println("Does it come here");
    if(testImagesList != null){
        //img = new ImageIcon(testImagesList.get(0));
        //BufferedImage img1 = ImageIO.read(new File(testImagesList.get(0)));
    }
    jF.setUndecorated(true);
    //System.out.println(testImagesList.get(0));
    System.out.println(testImagesPath);
    System.out.println("AbsolutePath=");
    System.out.println(testImagesPath.get(0));
    //System.out.println(testImagesA);
    //jF.add(new PanelForImages((new File(testImagesAbsoluteFilePaths.get(imageIndex)))));
    jF.add(new Component() {
      //  BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(file);

        //BufferedImage img1 = ImageIO.read(new File(testImagesPath.get(1)));



        BufferedImage img3 = ImageIO.read(new File(testImagesAbsoluteFilePaths.get(imageIndex))); 
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);

            g.drawImage(img3, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);


        }
    });

    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice gs = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    gs.setFullScreenWindow(jF);
    jF.validate();
}
```

Method I am using to switch between images. I am switching using the right arrow key which seems to be working fine. Its just that images that I have not drawn using the test program don't show.

```
 public void switchImageTest(int imageIndex ) throws IOException{

    jF.add(new Component(){
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(testImagesAbsoluteFilePaths.get(imageIndex)));
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g){
            super.paint(g);
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
            repaint();
        }
    });
    //GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    //GraphicsDevice gs = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    //gs.setFullScreenWindow(jF);
    //jF.repaint();
    jF.revalidate();
}
```

I hope this post makes sense to everyone. Please let me know if theres any doubt, I'll try to better explain it.

UPDATE: Managed to solve it, below is the updated code.

```
public class PanelForImages extends JPanel{

 private BufferedImage image;

 public PanelForImages(File image) throws IOException{
    //this.image = image;
    //URL resource = getClass().getResource("so2.jpg");
    this.image = ImageIO.read(image);

 }

 @Override
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    //super.paint(g);
    //super.paintComponents(g);
    super.paintComponent(g);
    //g.drawImage(image, 3, 4, this);
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
    g.drawString("HELLOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO", 400, 400);
    //repaint();

 }
}
```

The functions for showing the frame and switching images

```
public void showFrame(int imageIndex) throws IOException{
        System.out.println("Does it come here");
        if(testImagesList != null){
            //img = new ImageIcon(testImagesList.get(0));
            //BufferedImage img1 = ImageIO.read(new File(testImagesList.get(0)));
        }
        jF.setUndecorated(true);
        //System.out.println(testImagesList.get(0));
        System.out.println(testImagesPath);
        System.out.println("AbsolutePath=");
        System.out.println(testImagesPath.get(0));
        //System.out.println(testImagesA);
        //jF.add(new PanelForImages((new File(testImagesAbsoluteFilePaths.get(8)))));
        jF.add(panelForImages);


        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice gs = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
        gs.setFullScreenWindow(jF);
        jF.validate();
    }

public void switchImageTest(int imageIndex ) throws IOException{

     //jF.add(new PanelForImages(new      File(testImagesAbsoluteFilePaths.get(imageIndex))));
     jF.remove(panelForImages);
     panelForImages.removeAll();
     File currentImage = new   File(testImagesAbsoluteFilePaths.get(imageIndex));
     this.panelForImages = new PanelForImages(currentImage);
     jF.add(panelForImages);

     jF.validate();
}
```

Comment: Your code hasn't changed at all from when you last asked your question. Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates your problem using the suggestions from your last question. If you want us to take the time to read your question then you should take the time to read and understand our suggestions.

Comment: @camickr Sorry for the duplicate post. I tried various things but it didn't work. I have updated to what I am most recently trying. Only the image switching seems to be buggy, rest seems to be ok.

Comment: 1) This code is not an MCVE. The code can't be compiled and executed. 2) Never invoke repaint() inside a painting method.

Comment: @camickr Yeah, I managed to fix it. I hope the above isn't bad coding practise? Sorry, this is my first time working on a fairly big project.